# Is $t\mapsto 1_{[0,t]}(s)$ for a fixed $s\ge 0$ continous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Let $s\ge 0$ and $$f:[0,\infty)\to\left\{0,1\right\}\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto 1_{[0,t]}(s)$$
Is $f$ continuous at $t_0\ge 0$?

1. If $s>t_0$, then $f(t_0)=0=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$ for all $\left\{t_n\right\}\uparrow t_0$. So, $f$ is left-continuous at $t_0$.
2. If $s\le t_0$, then $f(t_0)=1=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$ for all $\left\{t_n\right\}\downarrow t_0$. So, $f$ is right-continuous at $t_0$.

If $s=t_0$, then $$f(t_0)=1\ne 0=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)\;\;\;\text{for all }\left\{t_n\right\}\uparrow t_0$$ So, $f$ cannot be (left-)continuous at $t_0=s$.

However: Is $f$ (right-)continuous at $t_0$ in the first case ($s>t_0$) and (left-)continuous at $t_0$ in the second case ($s<t_0$)?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to prove the statement if we note that $$f(t)=1_{[s,\infty)}(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\tag{1}\;.$$ From $(1)$ it's easy to observe that $f$ is continuous at each $t_0\ne s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you remarked in a comment: $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ can be presented as $1_{[s,\infty)}$.

This function is right-continuous everywhere and if $s>0$ then it is left-continuous everywhere except at $s$.

So if $s>0$ then $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $s$.

If $s=0$ then $f$ is constant hence continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, f is continuous everywhere except at $t_0 =s $. If $ s > t_0 $, then for all sequences $t_n$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t_0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ s > t_n $ (otherwise the sequence cannot converge to $t_0$). But then $f(t_n) = 0 $ for all $ n > N$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(t_n) = 0 = f(t_0)$. The same argument works for $s < t_0$.

Comment: I think, that I've made things too complicated. As I noted in my comment below the question, we've got $f\equiv 1_{]s,\infty)}$ in $[0,\infty)$ and from this representation it's easy to see, that $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $t_0=s$, right?